# Set variable to True if one of any conditions are met

Tags: python

I am checking for a long list of conditions, where each one looks something like this:

```
s = "string"
match = False

if "x" in s:
   variable = "something"
if "y" in s:
   variable = "something else"
if "z" in s:
   variable = "something something"
```

If any one of these are met, I want to set `match = True`.
Otherwise keep it at `match = False`.

I don't want to include `match = True` in each `if` statement because that would clutter up the code.

Is there a way to simply group all of these together, and if any condition is fulfilled, set `match = True`?

Comment: 2 ideas: Do you know [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)? You could do a set intersection and see if it is empty or not.

Comment: @falsetru There is no initial value for `variable`, it is set only if a condition is met.

Comment: `match = 'variable' in vars()`  OR  `match = variable != 'initial value'` if the `variable` has an initial value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize match with true and change it to false in else statement

```
s = "string"
match = True

if "z" in s:
   variable = "something something"
elif "y" in s:
   variable = "something else"
elif "x" in s:
   variable = "something"
else:
   match=False
```

Since in some case your all cases can be true so change the sequence of if statement to convert it to `elif` with still the same logic

Comment: Btw is it possible to use `or` with `elif` as: `elif "x" in s or "y" in s:`?

Comment: @Winterflags yeah it is , why don't you try that

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple hack for your problem 
list the tuples with conditions and check that weather True is in or not 
and do accordingly 
ex :
a = 1,2,3,4
conditions = (1 in a,5 in a,3 in a.....)//here the coditions holds series
                                          of  True or False values
                                           then check 
match = true if True in conditions